# special aggregation of matrix in dax?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a matrix and a basic numeric measure.

In my matrix I have Rows:

- Continent,
- country,
- city,
- street.

I want to have a special aggregation...

- For **street** level I want to show the value as it is.
- For **city** level, I want (sum of street) , but to show only if the value is negative. (otherwise show 0)
- For all above levels, I just want to sum whatever is in **city** level.

example 1

[image]

example 2

[image]

How can one do a special aggregation with IF case?

Comment: Interesting question of a hierarchy! Is it possible in DAX? Probably, yes! but keep in mind that DAX is not a language strong in hierarchy! SSAS is best tool in terms of managing hierarchies!

Comment: if i build the hierarchy in SSAS, how can this help me?

Comment: First, You have more control over hierarchies and Second, you have stronger language MDX (together with DAX) under your belt! Please understand that DAX is weak in terms of hierarchies! can't provide you enough functionalities!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That sounds like a confusing way to display your data but in answer to your question, you would make use of ISINSCOPE() to see which level of the hierarchy you're at.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/isinscope-function-dax